# IPB v3 version of ipsclass->txt_truncate()

Tags: php, frameworks, migration, invision-power-board

I am currently migrating an old IPB v2.x to a newer 3.x, however, I couldn't find the exact equivalent of this old syntax:

```
$this->ipsclass->txt_truncate();
```

Comment: Bummer. Do you have a question?

Comment: what's the new code for the ipb v3 of the mentioned syntax?

Comment: I'd be shocked if a random passer-by was able to answer this off the top of their head -- your best bet is almost certainly to consult the documentation for the library you're using.

Comment: OK I just found it, it is `IPSText::truncate();`

Comment: Congratulations! I'm not sure if you have enough rep to do so, but you should consider posting your findings as an answer to help people who may have the same problem in the future.

Comment: How should I? _Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking._ **You may self-answer in 6 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.**